# Edit multiple items at once in listbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox, edit, selected, items

For my application I want to edit multiple selected items at once in my Listbox.
Editing one item is no problem (just doing this by deleting the selected item and inserting a new one (with the text from my textbox) on the same place).
Now I have set my 'SelectionMode' to 'MultiSimple' so I can select multiple items.
However, I just can't find out how I can change them all at the same time.

Example: I have 10 items in my listbox and randomly select 4 of them. After I have selected them, I type 'VB.net' in my textbox. Then I click on the button 'Change' and then I want these selected items all to be replaced with 'VB.Net'

The code I currently have (but doesn't work):

```
Private Sub btnChange_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnChange.Click
    If listbox1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
        Dim iSelectedIndex As Integer = listbox1.SelectedIndex
        Dim strText As String = textbox1.Text

        For i = 1 To listbox1.SelectedItems.Count  
            listbox1.Items.RemoveAt(iSelectedIndex)
            listbox1.Items.Insert(iSelectedIndex, strText)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim iSelectedIndex As Integer` is a single Integer. You need the entire collection: `listBox1.SelectedIndices`. Cast its elements to an Integer value and build an Array of Integes to use as container for the Indexes. Then, you can iterate this collection: `For i = 0 To [MyArrayOfIntegers].Length`. Then, Insert([MyArrayOfIntegers](i), [Object]) and RemoveAt([MyArrayOfIntegers](i) +1). You can't use the original Collections (`SelectedIndices` and `SelectedItems`), because they will mutate when you add or remove items to the ListBox.Items Collection

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked!

Comment: @Jimi You might as well write that as an answer ;)